# Making the Text Output apply to a full column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to using VBA and I have a question that I don't feel like would be a very difficult thing to achieve.

```
Columns("A:C").Select
If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "194511" Then
Range("B1:B1000").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Base Reclamation"
Range("C1:C1000").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BaseRec Recont ED/LD/ME"
End If
```

In the text, I believe I have it to where I input a value anywhere in Column A and it should output the two text options displayed, but that's not the case. It only displays the text in the first row, but if I change "B1:B1000" to "B2" it will output data in the desired box.

If anybody could help me out it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This needs to go in the [Sheet module](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/code.htm) for the sheet you want it to work on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Text = "194511" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("Base Reclamation", _
                "BaseRec Recont ED/LD/ME")
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Or, in a normal code module:

```
[B1:C1000] = [IF($A1=194511,CHOOSE(COLUMN()-1,{""Base Reclamation"",""BaseRec Recont ED/LD/ME""}),"""")]
```

Comment: So, after inserting that into my sheet module everything should run smoothly? I feel like maybe my Range() syntax is wrong or something.

Comment: `ActiveCell` refers to the one (single) cell that is currently active. To be honest for what you need a formula would be best suited.